# making a youtube playlist using PHP. I get error. I am not sure what is going wrong

Tags: php, youtube

I am making a website, where people can search for music (from YouTube), and watch it on the same website. (no need of going to YouTube.)
In my database I have a table for playlist. The table has 4 values. ID, userID, artist and song.

id is the unique ID - I am using YouTube id for this- . 
userID is the id of the user. They can't use the playlist feature if they are logged in. I already have a database for that.

I have the following PHP code, where this information must be saved in the database, but it's not working.

```
if (isset($_SESSION['username'])){

                        echo '<button type="add to playlist" action="post">ADD</button>';


                        include 'playlistdb.php';
                        $sql = "insert into playlist (i,d,a,t) values ('$_POST[ID]','$_POST[userID]','$_POST[artist]','$_POST[title]')";
                        $result = mysql_query($sql,$conn) or die(mysql_error());
                    }
                    else{
                        echo "You are not logged in, you can use the playlist.";
                    }
```

but this doesn't work. I get the following error.

Notice: Undefined index: ID in C:\wamp\www\IKEPROJECT GROUP 9\video.php on line 112

and the same for userID, artist and title.

I am not sure what is going wrong here.

the error comes from this line:

```
$sql = "insert into playlist (i,d,a,t) values ('$_POST[ID]','$_POST[userID]','$_POST[artist]','$_POST[title]')";
```

Comment: what is at video.php line 112?

Comment: $sql = "insert into playlist (i,d,a,t) values ('$_POST[ID]','$_POST[userID]','$_POST[artist]','$_POST[title]')";

Comment: Ever heard about prepared statements?

Comment: **WARNING!** Your code contains an [SQL injection vulnerability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) -- you are passing raw, unfiltered, unvalidated user input directly into an SQL string. Please [switch to PDO](http://php.net/book.pdo) or [mysqli](http://php.net/book.mysqli) so you can use [prepared statements with parameterized queries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think button entities are wrong.use a format like this
`<button type="submit" formmethod="post" formaction="submit.php">ADD</button>`

Answer (score 1):

Consider using [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and formatting code in a readable way.

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare("insert into playlist (i,d,a,t) values (?, ?, ?, ?)");
$sth->execute(array($_POST['ID'], $_POST['userID'], $_POST['artist'], $_POST['title']));
```

If there is still an error, make sure you have valid input field for that with name 'ID'.

Comment: Did you initialize PDO before using it? `$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=YOUR_DB_HOST;dbname=DBNAME", "USER", "PASSWORD");`

Answer (score 0):

You need quote marks-- it's not $_POST[ID], it's $_POST['ID']. See Saeed Najafi's comment for the property PHP formatting.

Additionally you do have a serious SQL injection vulnerability in your code... it's extremely important you fix that or else someone could hack your site, erase your db, etc.